# How to pass my dynamic id to the Tabs When onChnageTab function called in Native-base Tabs

Tags: react-native, dynamic, tabs, native-base, react-native-tab-view

***I need to pass the `items.id` into `OnChangeTab`***
*I have use the tabs from the `native-base` library insted of index I want to send the dynamic id so that I can send the same id to my api*

```
   <Tabs
            // locked={true}
            tabBarUnderlineStyle={{backgroundColor: '#E60000'}}
            onChangeTab={({i}) => this.handleClickCat(i)}
            renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTab />}>
            {this.props.data &&
              this.props.data.map((items, index) => {
                return (
                  <Tab
                    heading={
                      <TabHeading>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                          onPress={() => this.setState({id: items.id})}>
                          <Text>{items.title}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                      </TabHeading>
                    }
                   key={items.id}
                    tabStyle={{backgroundColor: '#1D1E1F'}}
                    // onChangeTab={() => this.handleClickCat()}
                    // activeTab={() => this.setState({id: items.id})}
                    // o={this.setState({id: items.id})}
                    activeTabStyle={{backgroundColor: '#1D1E1F'}}
                    textStyle={{color: '#9E9E9E'}}
                    activeTextStyle={{color: '#FFFFFF'}}>
                    <AllNewsScrolimage
                      navigation={this.props.navigation}
                      data={this.props.catdata}
                      id={items.id}
                    />
                  </Tab>
                );
              })}
          </Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `i` is the index of tab so you can get item's id by doing like

```
handleClickCat(index){    
  const itemId = this.props.data[index].id; // Item id here
}

onChangeTab={({i}) => this.handleClickCat(i)}
```

Comment: i  have doone this but i want to pass my **tems.id** insted of **i** in function **onchnageTab** `handleClickCat = (id) => {
    // alert(id);

    this.fetchDefaultdata(id);
  
  };`

Comment: NativeBase library default provides an index of Tab in its onChangeTab function. If you want items.id in onChangeTab instead of the index then you have to customize it accordingly. I can help you out with that but my answer will result you same as you required. You have your data set in props, so easily you can get an item's id from that

Comment: Hello i got the answer now thank you for  your help as `onChangeTab={({ref}) => this.handleClickCat(ref.props.id)}` as **<Tab id={items.id} />**

Comment: Yes, ref provides props that can access it. Greate :-)